# How do I create /etc/subversion?

Tags: intellij-idea, svn, config, centos6

A little bit of background. I have a Centos6 VM that I've installed IntelliJ onto, and I've added the subversion plugin to it. The VM has subversion-1.7.22 installed.

I noticed that there was an issue when I went to configure my repositories; the url I provided, when expanded, stuck on "Loading..." and wouldn't show the trunk or branches. Checking the idea.log file, I found that the ins.idea.svn.IdeaSVNConfigFile was throwing a FileNotFoundException; namely, anything in the `/etc/subversion` directory.

This directory, ostensibly, is supposed to contain the configuration for the system-wide settings for subversion. Yet it doesn't exist on my system.

My Subversion installation is located in `/root/subversion-1.7.22`.

Is there something I'm missing or forgot to do? Why was `/etc/subversion` not created when I did my `configure` and `make install`? Should I have started from `/etc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you installed subversion in a non-standard place (`/root/subversion-1.7.22` is not a standard install), you need to reconfigure your installation to not look in the Operating System's standard place.

You might already have the config file you need in `/root/subversion-1.7.22/etc/subversion.conf` or some other sub-directory of `/root/subversion-1.7.22`  If so, I'd start with that one.

If you find it hard to reconfigure your system to look for the /etc/subversion.conf file within the /root installation directory, I'd look for a packaged version of Subversion, which will have done this system integration work for you.

Comment: Okay. I'll do some investigation. Thank you so much for your answer.